# Parsing Complex JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I've been trying to parse this complex JSON file from the website:

https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?rsn=hotcrumbs&old_stats=1

I need the JSON to be parsed into a object that I can then use to print out certain values into the console.

```
{"orig_rsn":"hotcrumbs","rsn":"hotcrumbs","stats":{"overall":
{"level":167,"exp":38759},"attack":{"level":20,"exp":4493},"defence":
{"level":20,"exp":4497},"strength":{"level":10,"exp":1185},"constitution":
{"level":26,"exp":8884},"range":{"level":30,"exp":13448},"prayer":
{"level":10,"exp":1188},"magic":{"level":2,"exp":102},"cooking":
{"level":9,"exp":1030},"woodcutting":{"level":15,"exp":2590},"fletching":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"fishing":{"level":5,"exp":500},"firemaking":
{"level":4,"exp":360},"crafting":{"level":1,"exp":0},"smithing":
{"level":1,"exp":80},"mining":{"level":5,"exp":402},"herblore":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"agility":{"level":1,"exp":0},"thieving":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"slayer":{"level":1,"exp":0},"farming":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"runecrafting":{"level":1,"exp":0},"hunter":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"construction":{"level":1,"exp":0},"summoning":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"dungeoneering":{"level":1,"exp":0},"divination":
{"level":1,"exp":0},"duel":{"level":1},"bh":{"level":1},"bhr":
{"level":1},"fog":{"level":1}}}
```

As you can see the JSON is very complex especially as it's the first JSON project i've worked on.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to paste this as a class in Visual Studio, then use newtonsoft to deserialize into that class. The structure seems very simple and it should just work

Comment: Most robots that generate classes for you will treat those `level/exp` sets as separate classes but it can easily be collapsed to one.  Deserializing is simpler than parsing

Comment: @Plutonix are you saying that each of the different stats should be seperate classes like:'        public class Attack
        {
            public int level { get; set; }
            public int exp { get; set; }
        }'

Comment: No, I am saying the opposite.  Most of the class generators do not optimize and will create a class for each of range, magic, attack...etc.  But they are all the same and can be collapsed

Comment: any help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323300/access-complex-json-inner-objects-deserilization-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the classes to hold the various json objects. You can paste your json into: http://json2csharp.com/ and it will create your classes.

Once you have your classes created you can use below to Deserialize into whatever you need

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

You then have full access to the various objects/properties as in the example below:

```
Console.WriteLine(rootObject.stats.agility.level)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, +10000. thank you so much.

Comment: @AchillesDH don't forget the *Plutonix*'s comment

Answer (score 0):

I highly recomment to using "newtonsoft.Json" package if possible: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

First Install the nuget package to your project:

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.3

Then you can Convert it like in this short example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        class Stats
        {
            public int level;
            public int exp;
        }
        class InputObj
        {
            public string orig_rsn;
            public string rsn;
            public Dictionary<string, Stats> stats;
        }
        const string sampleString = "{\"orig_rsn\":\"hotcrumbs\",\"rsn\":\"hotcrumbs\",\"stats\":{\"overall\":{\"level\":167,\"exp\":38759},\"attack\":{\"level\":20,\"exp\":4493},\"defence\":{\"level\":20,\"exp\":4497},\"strength\":{\"level\":10,\"exp\":1185},\"constitution\":{\"level\":26,\"exp\":8884},\"range\":{\"level\":30,\"exp\":13448},\"prayer\":{\"level\":10,\"exp\":1188},\"magic\":{\"level\":2,\"exp\":102},\"cooking\":{\"level\":9,\"exp\":1030},\"woodcutting\":{\"level\":15,\"exp\":2590},\"fletching\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"fishing\":{\"level\":5,\"exp\":500},\"firemaking\":{\"level\":4,\"exp\":360},\"crafting\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"smithing\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":80},\"mining\":{\"level\":5,\"exp\":402},\"herblore\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"agility\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"thieving\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"slayer\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"farming\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"runecrafting\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"hunter\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"construction\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"summoning\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"dungeoneering\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"divination\":{\"level\":1,\"exp\":0},\"duel\":{\"level\":1},\"bh\":{\"level\":1},\"bhr\":{\"level\":1},\"fog\":{\"level\":1}}}";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputObj>(sampleString);
            //System.Console.WriteLine(customer1.orig_rsn);
            foreach( var x in customer1.stats)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Key: "+x.Key);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Level: " + x.Value.level);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Exp: " + x.Value.exp);
            }
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: How would I go about getting a value that has been nested for example: Stats > Attack > Exp

Comment: I have now added the declaration and an example to read the stats.