# Access complex JSON inner objects deserilization using c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I have a COMPLEX JSON which I need to deserialize and access all its objects. My JSON looks like this

```
{
    "name": {},
    "percentage": [
        {
            "math": {
                "2.503300099.1": 460800,
                "2.503300099.2": 460800,
                "2.503300099.3": 460800,
                "2.503308292.1": 2457600,
                "2.503308292.2": 2457600,
                "2.503308292.3": 2457600
            },
            "english": {
                "2.503300099": "hello",
                "2.503308292": "hi"
            },

            "exam": "2.0"
        }
    ],
    "class": {},
    "section": "7.17.1",
    "total": 1
}
```

The values of JSON may change, number of times they appear may also change.

What I can access so far is name,class,section,total,and issue is with percentage part. I can reach till percentage also but I cant access math or English, or exam with their values.

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                 
  JObject Search = JObject.Parse(content);                  
  Speed res = new Speed();

res.class= Search["class"].ToString();  // good
res.english = Search["english"].ToString();// not good
```

Any help or suggestion please ?

**EDIT**

After so many questions of the structure of JSON, I would like to clarify that structure wont changes ever but the number of objects may, lets understand this with an example:

```
{
    "One": {},
    "Two": [
        {
            "twoA": {
                "2.503300099.1": 460800,
                "2.503300099.2": 460800,
                 "...." : ...,
                 "...." : ...,
            },
            "TwoB": {
                "2.503300099": "value",
                "2.503308292": "value"
                "...." : ...,
                "...." : ...,
            },
             "TwoC": {
                "2.503300099": "value",
                "2.503308292": "value"
                "...." : ...,
                "...." : ...,
            },
            "exam": "2.0",
            "...." : ...,
            "...." : ...,
        }
    ],
    "Three": {empty},
    "Four": "value string",
    "Five": value int
    .....
    .....
}
```

Hope this clarifies doubt on JSON structure

Comment: Why dont you try a generating class from json. Copy json to clip board and  in visual studio  Edit->Paste Special -> Paste Json As Classes . Visual Studio will generate your object class automatically. 
Then you can directly parse content string to your object.

Comment: You realize, off course, that having property names like "2.503300099.1" is not optimal (or even a valid property name in C#)?

Comment: but the JSON is not always like this as i have written in the question, it may change with the name or with the number of child

Comment: @OskarLindberg thats correct that is another issue but we can fix that if JSON is always the same.

Comment: @Learner Well, if you structure your object (json) nicely, and parse as a specific type, e.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` (or whatever, you can do un-typed parsing as well, it doesn't matter), you should have no issues.

Comment: @OskarLindberg JSON i am consuming from web api where I dont have any control, if you could elaborate more  would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments on your question and subsequent answers it would seem that the data from the API is unpredictable to the extent that I'd begin arguing that the people responsible for that API should take a step back and rethink their approach. I don't see how you could ever parse *any* data without as much as hint as to how that data might be structured.

But maybe I'm overreacting...

Maybe parsing the data as a `dynamic` is the answer you're looking for? Using this approach, you can do things like:

```
const string data = "{\"1123.5433\":{\"42.42.42\":\"bazinga\"}}";
var myDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);

Console.WriteLine(myDynamic["1123.5433"]["42.42.42"]); // -> bazinga;
```

The path for a value in `math` in your example, if I'm not mistaken, would be something like:

```
myDynamic["percentage"][0]["math"]["2.503300099.1"]; // ~ 460800?
```

Not very readable though. Or stable. So, I reside, back to ponder my original quandary of what manner of creature thought up the API in question...

**EDIT:** Updates to reflect comments and changes in the original question:

```
// First example
const string originalExample =
    "{\"name\": {},\"percentage\": [{\"math\": {\"2.503300099.1\": 460800,\"2.503300099.2\": 460800},\"english\": {\"2.503300099\": \"hello\"}}]}";
var myFirstDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(originalExample);

Console.WriteLine(myFirstDynamic["percentage"][0]["math"]["2.503300099.1"]); // -> 460800

// Second example
const string newExample =
            "{\"One\": {},\"Two\": [{\"twoA\": {\"2.503300099.1\": 460800,\"2.503300099.2\": 460800,},\"TwoB\": {\"2.503300099\": \"value\",\"2.503308292\": \"value\"},\"TwoC\": {\"2.503300099\": \"value\",\"2.503308292\": \"value\"},\"exam\": \"2.0\"}]}";
var mySecondDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(newExample);

Console.WriteLine(mySecondDynamic["Two"][0]["twoA"]["2.503300099.1"]); // -> 460800;
```

Given the structure you present in your second example, you could also define suitable types to fit that same structure:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<MyNextObject> Two { get; set; }
}

public class MyNextObject
{
    public dynamic twoA { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize and parse like this:

```
var deserializedToType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(newExample);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedToType.Two.First().twoA["2.503300099.1"]); // -> 460800;
```

Because the property names in the source data are not valid for C#, you still need the `dynamic` typing in those places where problems would otherwise occur (e.g. `MyNextObject.twoA`). Also, depending on what you're trying to do and in what context, enumerating the children of `percentage` etc. may be a better choice than going for specific indexes.

Note that I'm using the exact same json structure as you presented in all my examples, albeit shortened in the end for brevity and escaped to present working examples.

Where your source property names are inconsistent, invalid or not adhering common praxis, to keep your C# code clean, you should probably use some method of mapping values between source and target. E.g. if you're using Json.NET, things like the `JsonProperty` attribute.

Also, please not that I'm not presenting "production like code" here. You should obviously take care and handle potential problems such as `null` values or out-of-bound indexes properly.

Comment: this will through you out with  run time binding on a null reference error

Comment: My example, the first piece of code, runs fine. The second piece of code was just an approximation from deciphering the json string in your example on-the-fly. Did you get the gist, though?

Comment: but thats not the correct structure of JSON, the second approach is something i am looking for as working and thats where it doesnt reach due to null reference

Comment: You're clearly doing something else wrong. I tested my off-the-top-of-my-head-example, and it works fine, see edit.

Comment: I think you mistake the purpose of StackOverflow. It's not about having other people do your work for you, but about having a specific problem and ask people for strategies or methods to solve those. I presented such a strategy to you, and it's viable given the information you provided. That said, I've now presented three different working examples for you. The next time, you should begin with presenting some runnable piece of code yourself.

Comment: I think you have mistaken the purpose of post, and it has become a fashion commenting these statements just to gain publicity. I am not asking you to do my work, I am just asking for suggestions on specific part where I am stuck and if you read the post properly you will understand. You might be expert on something so if you like help or let it be. This forum is open for discussion, suggestion, and help not to comment on questions. Thank you for your time so far with this post.